# expose results by text file output step in JOB kettle

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I want to expose results in a JOB kettle using text file output (by checking pass results to output checkbox), but i can't find the text file output step in a Job pentaho, so what's the solution.
I already do that by a transformation by calling carte web service, so i get results in my browser, the question is about doing that in a job.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a feature similar to Text file output in a PDI Job, you won't find it since Pentaho Jobs are more about high level design which execute the transformations, sending mails, failures, etc.. The closest you can get is **Write to Logs** step in Pentaho jobs.

Comment: the reason why i want that feature in kettle job is that the job can iterate multiple rows, and for each row i expose a result so if can i ietrate rows with transformation it will be also a solution ,so i am asking if there is a possibility to iterate in transformation???

Answer (score 0):

When you need to iterate, you need to go to transformations. That's what they're designed for.
You can iterate in jobs, doing some things like while-loop, althoug it's not recommended for a very deep looping. (see http://vrubleuski.blogspot.com.ar/2010/08/implementing-while-loop-in-kettle.html)

But returning to your problem, you are not very specific on what the data you're getting is, or what is the expected output.

Let's assume you have a transformation which generates the data you need to expose. On that transformation you implement a final step called "Copy rows to result".

On your parent job you have 2 possibilities:

1) Put a transformation there and check the "Execute for every input row?" and "Copy previous results to parameters?". After that, define one parameter for each relevant column you need to pass to that transformation and inside it do the text file output.

2) Put the transformation there, don't check anything, and inside it use the Get rows from result step. That will pick up the previously copied result from the data-generating transformation and then use the text file output connected to it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you that's what I am doing actually, but kindly if you can tell me how can I pass the file output content to servlet in a job??